# Use first 3 characters of a filename as a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

this is my first post so hopefully I will make my question clear.

I am new to shell scripts and my task with this one is to add a new value to every line of a csv file. The value that needs added is based on the first 3 digits of the filename.

I bit of background. The csv files I am receiving are eventually being loaded into partitioned oracle tables. The start of the file name (e.g. BATTESTFILE.txt) contains the partitioned site so I need to write a script that takes the first 3 characters of the filename (in this example BAT) and add this to the end of each line of the file.

The closest I have got so far is when I stripped the code to the bare basics of what I need to do:

```
build_files()                                          
{                                                      
    OLDFILE=${filename[@]}.txt                     
    NEWFILE=${filename[@]}.NEW.txt                 
    ABSOLUTE='path/scripts/'        
    FULLOLD=$ABSOLUTE$OLDFILE                      
    FULLNEW=$ABSOLUTE$NEWFILE                      
    sed -e s/$/",${j}"/ "${FULLOLD}" > "${FULLNEW}"
}                                                      

set -A site 'BAT'                                      
set -A filename 'BATTESTFILE'                          

for j in ${site[@]};  do                               

    for i in ${filename[@]}; do                    
            build_files ${j}                       
    done                                           

done
```

Here I have set up an array `site` as there will be 6 'sites' and this will make it easy to add additionals sits to the code as the files come through to me. The same is to be siad for the `filename` array.

This codes works, but it isn't as automated as I need. One of my most recent attempts has been below:

```
build_files()                                          
{                                                      
    OLDFILE=${filename[@]}.txt                     
    NEWFILE=${filename[@]}.NEW.txt                 
    ABSOLUTE='/app/dss/dsssis/sis/scripts/'        
    FULLOLD=$ABSOLUTE$OLDFILE                      
    FULLNEW=$ABSOLUTE$NEWFILE                      
    sed -e s/$/",${j}"/ "${FULLOLD}" > "${FULLNEW}"
}                                                      

set -A site 'BAT'                                      
set -A filename 'BATTESTFILE'                          

for j in ${site[@]};  do                               

    for i in ${filename[@]}; do                    
    trust=echo "$filename" | cut -c1-3             
    echo "$trust"                                  
    if ["$trust" = 'BAT']; then                    
    ${j} = 'BAT'                                   
    fi                                             
    build_files ${j}                               
    done                                           
done
```

I found the code `trust=echo "$filename" | cut -c1-3` through another question on StackOverflow as I was researching, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I added in the `echo` to test what `trust` was holding, but it was empty.

I am getting 2 errors back:
Line 17 - BATTESTFILE:  not found
Line 19 - test: ] missing

Sorry for the long winded questions. Hopefully It contains helpful info and shows the steps I have taken. Any questions, comment away. Any help or guidance is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Looks like ksh. Which version? Try `ksh --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are new with shells, try avoiding arrays.
In an if statement use spaces before and after the [ and ] characters.
Get used to surrounding your shell variables with {} like ${trust}

I do not know how you fill your array, when the array is hardcoded, try te replace with
SITE=file1
SITE="${SITE} file2"

And you must tell unix you want to have the rightside eveluated with $(..) (better than backtics):

```
trust=$(echo "${filename}" | cut -c1-3)
```

Some guidelines and syntax help can be found at [Google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml)

Comment: Thanks Walter. I changed my line to what you suggested (added in the brackets) and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Just use shell [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ var=abcdefg
$ echo "${var:0:3}"
abc
```

Assuming you're using a reasonably capable shell like bash or ksh, for example

Comment: Thanks for your response Glenn. That link is really useful. I have it bookmarked for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is useful for anyone else now or in the future, I got my code to work as desired by using the below. Thanks Walter A below for his answer to my main problem of getting the first 3 characters from the filename and using them as a variable.

This gave me the desired output of taking the first 3 characters of the filename, and adding them to the end of each line in my csv file.

```
## Get the current Directory and file name, create a new file name
build_files()                                                                   
{                                                                               
    OLDFILE=${i}.txt                                                        
    NEWFILE=${i}.NEW.txt                                                    
    ABSOLUTE='/app/dss/dsssis/sis/scripts/'                                 
    FULLOLD=$ABSOLUTE$OLDFILE                                               
    FULLNEW=$ABSOLUTE$NEWFILE 

## Take the 3 characters from the filename and 
## add them onto the end of each line in the csv file.

    sed -e s/$/";${j}"/ "${FULLOLD}" > "${FULLNEW}"                         
}                                                                               

## Loop to take the first 3 characters from the file names held in
## an array to be added into the new file above  

set -A filename 'BATTESTFILE'                             

    for i in ${filename[@]}; do                                             
    trust=$(echo "${i}" | cut -c1-3)                                        
    echo "${trust}"                                                         
    j="${trust}"                                                            
    echo "${i} ${j}"                                                        
    build_files ${i} ${j}                                                   

done
```

Hope this is useful for someone else.

Comment: Don't use `$i` and `$j` in your function, use the passed in values as `$1` and `$2` respectively (or don't bother to pass the values at all.